# Pictures in a row in HTML

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to put in formulas in 3 columns, I followed the guide on how to write HTML file to do it, but the pictures are nowhere to be found for some reason. The problem is that I ahve to use C# for that one, so made my own class to create an HTML file. I do not understand what exactly could have gone wrong.

[image]

Comment: Please include the HTML and CSS in a code snippet in the question to demonstrate the problem.  Also, how is this in any way related to C#?

Comment: Typo - should be `src` not `scr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try using src instead of scr in img

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I've tried it on my system.